# How can i use an image as a background in Blender Render?

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I mean to say that for reflective materials like metal, I want that image as world material so that I get the cool reflections.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE Milin. Please take a look around before asking in the future. A good amount of questions have been answered already. You can also see these as they might relate to what you want.. [How to capture lighting in video shots?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/412/how-to-capture-lighting-in-video-shots) and [How to make a model cast shadows onto the world texture/background?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background)

Comment: Also, try to keep your posts as specific as possible, using *OR* wouldn't be ideal in this case as posts should *ideally* have **one** question and **one** answer, ask for both or one.